# $\varphi(d)$ elements of order $d$ in $\mathbb{U}_n$ (defined in the question)

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, totient-function, roots-of-unity

> $$\mathbb{U}_{n\in\mathbb N^*}=\left\{\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right),\,0\leq k\leq n-1\right\}$$
> $$\varphi(d)=\text{card}\{k\in[[1,d]],\,\text{gcd}(k,d)=1\}$$
> If $z\in\mathbb U_n$, we call order of $z$ the smallest integer $d\geq1$ such that $z^d=1$.
> Let $d\in[[1,n-1]]$ such that $d|n$ (say $n=dc$ for some $c\in\mathbb N$).
>
> Show that there are exactly $\varphi(d)$ elements of order $d$ in $\mathbb{U}_n$.

*I'm going to use $a\wedge b\,$ for the gcd.*
$[[a,b]]$ is an integer interval.

Let $z\in\mathbb U_n$ and let it be of order $d$, then
$$z^d=\exp\left[\left(i\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)d\right]=\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi k}{c}\right)=1$$
Since $z$ is of order $d$, $k=k'c=k'\frac nd$ for some $k'\in\mathbb N$ (or else $c$ doesn't divide $k$).
Claim: For the above to hold, we require that $k'\wedge d=1$.

Proof: Suppose that $k'\wedge d>1$, then $z=\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)=\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi k'}{d}\right)$.

Because $k'\wedge d>1$, we get $z=\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi a}{b}\right)$ where $b<d$, thus the order of $z$ is at worst $b$, and could be less if $a\wedge b>1$, which goes against the first hypothesis that the order of $z$ is $d$.
In the above, I have put $k'=a(k'\wedge d)$ and $d=b(k'\wedge d)$ for some $a,\,b\in\mathbb N$.

There are $\varphi(d)$ of such $k'$, therefore:

> there are exactly $\varphi(d)$ elements of order $d$ in $\mathbb{U}_n$

If anything is amiss, then please let me know. Thank you for your time!

Comment: In the beginning of your proof, you say "Let $z \in \mathbb U_n$ and let it be of order $d$, then $z^d = \exp(i \frac{2\pi k}{c})$."  This is confusing.  First, you never say what $c$ is, and second, $z^d$ should be $1$.

Comment: Overall your proof is confusing.  You should say what variables are when you introduce them.  Also, it is confusing to use the unit circle here.  Probably a proof is much clearer which uses the additive group $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ instead of $\mathbb U_n$, the isomorphism being given by $k +\mathbb Z \mapsto \exp(i \frac{2 \pi i k}{n})$.

Comment: hey @D_S, and thanks for having read my post. i have tried to clear things a bit more, but i can't come up with a proof using what you are suggesting. that's a bit beyond the scope of what i know.

Comment: Do you know what the "integers modulo $n$" are?  Like $0, 1, 2, ... , n-1$ and then it repeats back to $0$?

Comment: sure, I do. but i don't know the properties surrounding what you mentioned. in any case, the context in which the exercise is given is not such that i need to use that.

Answer (score 0):

In short, this is true because $U_n\cong\Bbb Z_n$.

And a basic fact about cyclic groups is that $|g|=d\implies |g^k|=\dfrac d{(d,k)}$.  It follows by taking a generator that there's a unique cyclic subgroup of order $d$ for every $d$ dividing $n$, and that there are $\varphi(d)$ generators for that subgroup.

Comment: thank you for having taken the time to post an answer to the problem, but i wanted someone to comment on what i have done.

Comment: yeah, i figured that.  I only got through a little bit of it.  But it really boils down to the $n$-th roots  of unity forming a cyclic group, of order $n$.